# Java execute method on all objects in a List

Tags: java

I've got such an interface:

```
public interface Listener {
    void onA();
    void onB();
    void onC();
}
```

And there is a list of listeners/observers:

```
List<Listener> listeners = new ArrayList<Listener>();
```

How can I easily inform all listeners, that A, B, C occurred via `Listener.onA()`, `Listener.onB()`, `Listener.onC()`?

Do I have to copy-paste iteration over all listeners at least three times?

In C++ I would create such a function:

```
void Notify(const std::function<void(Listener *listener)> &command) {
  for(auto &listener : listeners) {
    command(listener);
  }
}
```

And pass lambda for each of methods:

```
Notify([](Listener *listener) {listener->onA();});
```

or

```
Notify([](Listener *listener) {listener->onB();});
```

or

```
Notify([](Listener *listener) {listener->onC();});
```

Is there a similar approach in Java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java 8, there is:

```
listeners.forEach(listener -> listener.onA());
```

or:

```
listeners.forEach(Listener::onA);
```

Note that there's a host of other functional-programming-style operations that can be performed with lambda functions, but most of them will require that you first create a *stream* from your collection by calling `.stream()` on it. `forEach()`, as I learned from the comments, is an exception to this.

Comment: You don't need 'stream'.  The `List` has a `forEach` method directly on it

Comment: Simply `foreach` without `stream`

Comment: @tddmonkey and Yassin Hajaj: Thanks; I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: where did you find those information? I know java 8 support lamda but how do you know it can be used like this?

Comment: @user3659052: Java 8 added not only lambda function but the _stream_ concept and a bunch of methods for manipulating them with lambdas, so you might want to read up on streams.

Answer (score 1):

If your java version is not allowing a Lambdas then do:

```
List<Listener> l = ...
for (Listener myListeners : listenersList) {
    myListeners.onA();
    myListeners.onB();
    myListeners.onC();
}
```